# Can some please tell me why my rndc reload in Linux is not working?

Tags: domain-name-system

```
sudo rndc reload
rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
rndc reload
rndc: error: open: /etc/bind/rndc.key: permission denied
rndc: could not load rndc configuration
```

I am getting all these errors

Comment: What was not clear in the errors you got? First one tells you that nothing is listening at that IP address and port, so double check exactly where you should connect for rndc, and the second error clearly tells you you are trying to read a file that you are not allowed to read, so maybe not correct users or wrong permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just forgot to change to Root or use `sudo`?

```
> id && rndc reload
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
server reload successful
```

```
> id && rndc reload
uid=1000(cb) gid=1000(cb) groups=1000(cb),4(adm),27(sudo),1006(rvm)
rndc: error: open: /etc/bind/rndc.key: permission denied
rndc: could not load rndc configuration
```

But the Port-Problem seems more like the Service isn't running at all.
You could check it with `systemctl status named` and if it runs maybe a Firewall is Blocking Access something like `ufw`?

`stat /etc/bind/rndc.key`

Comment: A firewall would result into a timeout (and there is no firewall on the localhost interface, even if one is running). Connection refused indicates that the service is not running.